# How python assigns unique memory address to string "sample" ? when each character is stored in different location

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, memory-management

How python assigns unique memory address to string "sample" ,
as it uses 6 cells to store the unicode character in string "SAMPLE" as these 6 cells point to 12 memory address (since 1 cells points to 2 memory address)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The C Python implementation wraps strings in a C structure that includes string type, length and a pointer to the memory holding the string. Each character in the string could be represented by 1 (UCS1), 2 (UCS2) or 4 (UCS4) bytes. Python only keeps the address of the first character and the the length of the string. It can then find any character in the string by simple math on that pointer. For UCS2, the character at some `index` is `pointer + (sizeof_character * index)`.

Comment: i did not understand this points, "Python only keeps the address of the first character and the the length of the string"  so should we consider that the entire string is not stored in memory address ?  I the screenshot you can see "S" is stored in 2 memory address 2146,2147 but when you execute id('S') it return only 1 memory address  . Likewise is  the whole string "SAMPLE" also in stored in some memory address ? if so  how its stored and how a unique address is assigned to it